# How to compile static collectd?

Tags: perl, unix, gcc, compilation, collectd

I'm trying to compile static collectd:

```
cd collectd-5.4.1/
./configure --enable-debug --enable-cpu --enable-df --enable-disk --enable-interface --enable-load --enable-memory --enable-processes --enable-rrdtool --enable-snmp --enable-statsd --enable-logfile --disable-shared --with-librrd=/opt/local
make all
```

after that I see  an error:

```
  CC     perl_la-perl.lo
perl.c:44:21: error: poisoning existing macro [-Werror]
# pragma GCC poison sprintf
                ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [perl_la-perl.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix might be to disable the perl plugin, if you don't need it